# Пошаговое описание десктопного клиент приложения на Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, api, клиент

Доброго времени суток

Просьба у меня довольно обычна для новичка в программировании. Заключается она в том, что я хочу сделать клиент приложение для VK, а познаний мало от слова совсем. Поэтому буду очень признателен если вы сможете описать поэтапно создание (использование API, получение токена, как его использовать), т.к. опыт был только в создании клиент-серверного приложения на плюсах. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

1. Прочитайте учебник по Java
2. Прочитайте документацию VK SDK
3. Попытайтесь написать приложение
4. Если что-то не получится, создайте вопрос на SO с описание конкретной проблемы.